# Unix: Same executable, different user: different executable version?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, version

I'm being very confused by the following happening in my terminal:

```
my-computer:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java

my-computer:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)

my-computer:~$ sudo su
Password:

my-computer:/Users/paulhabfast$ which java
/usr/bin/java

my-computer:/Users/paulhabfast$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Can anyone explain me what is going on?
The way I understand it so far is that when I switch from the current user to the root user, I'm being served a different executable?

I'm running Mac OSX 10.9, but I thought I had a pretty standard unix environment.

Is there any additional information I can give?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/usr/bin/java` is a wrapper that looks at your environment variables, try `env` to see these variables, for example `JAVA_HOME`.